# What's those underscore commands?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, linux-mint

When I `tab tab` `_` in terminal, Bash suggests 206 posibilities. I tried to run one of them `_git_rm` but nothing happend, what are they?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `type _git_rm` will probably tell you that it is a function. `grep -R '_git_rm' /etc/bash_completion.d/` will probably find it. Those functions are usually those which provide the various completion lists for `bash` completion.

Comment: @manatwork please post that as an answer.

Comment: @derobert, I only intended to provide a quick hint so the question owner gets something before the expert answer posted ~7 hours later.

Comment: @manatwork The answer is enough for me... I can explore more by myself :D If you don't mind, I'll accept Gilles's anwser though I think I should accept yours..

Comment: @draw, Gilles' answer is probably based on research and experience, while mine is based on accidental observations made during directory crawling. Please accept his.

Comment: @manatwork ok...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These functions whose name begins with an underscore are part of the programmable completion engine. Bash follows zsh's convention here, where the function that generates completions for `somecommand` is called `_somecommand`, and if that function requires auxiliary functions, they are called `_somecommand_stuff`.

These completion functions typically do nothing useful or raise an error if you call them manually: they're intended to be called from the completion engine.

This follows on a fairly widespread practice in various programming languages to use a leading underscore to indicate that a function or variable is in some way internal to a library and not intended for the end-user (or end-programmer).